# Digital Signature in AX 2009 + PDF

Tags: digital-signature, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I have vouchers which has to be digitally signed by the higher official abc, xyz.

I know that digital signature has to be added in the PDF file (report output), but not sure how, also that certain methods of PDF has to be called from Axapta but don't know what those methods are and how they can be called.

Kindly assist me on how to approach.

Comment: PDF files does not have methods.

Comment: does this concept has anything to do with 'electronic Signature' concept in AX. I doubt.

Comment: An electronic signature by itself is not the same as a digital signature. An electronic signature is simply a substitute for a handwritten signature, while a digital signature provides additional security measures. Then what is your question?

Comment: got my answer... Thanks again, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An electronic signature by itself is not the same as a digital signature. An electronic signature is simply a substitute for a handwritten signature, while a digital signature provides additional security measures.

### Digital signature

I would recommend that the PDF is generated by AX as normal, then [digitally sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) it after the higher official has read and approved the document. The signature has to be applied after document generation, because it contains a hash of its content.

The signature could be done by third party software.

Start by reading [Adobe's page on the matter](http://www.adobe.com/security/digsig.html).

### Electronic signature

AX 2012 has some functionality, [start here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362020.aspx).

AX 2009, see [Dilip's blog](http://daxdilip.blogspot.dk/2008/04/whats-new-in-dynamics-ax-2009-dynamics.html), also remember to enable the [configuration key](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/axlachlancash/archive/2009/08/18/electronic-signature.aspx).

> Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 does not provide a complete system for the capture and processing of electronic signatures. But it does provide a kernel event and an editable event method. These can be the foundation for an electronic signature subsystem to be developed by partners

The AX 2009 SP1 [What's new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc602654%28v=ax.50%29.aspx#ESignature) goes:

> Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 SP1 provides a system for capturing and for processing electronic signatures. The system provides several built-in signatures, such as Bill of Material Approval.
>
> You can enable the built-in signatures by using the Electronic signature requirements form. This form also enables the administrator to define new signatures for tables or fields. Defining new signatures requires careful planning to avoid excessive security which could block proper access to tables.
>
> For more information about using built-in signatures or defining new signatures, see "Electronic signature requirements (form)" in System and Application Setup Help. In the SP1 edition of the Help, see "Generic electronic signatures".